# OS X SDK 10.5 version of dispatch_queue_t

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, osx-leopard

I'm hoping to convert this 10.6 code to 10.5:

```
@autoreleasepool {

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue,^(){

      // contact webservice for IP-address information

      // update UI (NSMenuItem)

    });
}
```

What I have so far:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  // background process

    // contact webservice for IP-address information

    // update UI (NSMenuItem)

  // end background process

[pool drain];
```

It appears that a can use `dispatch_async`, but not `blocks` and `dispatch_queue_t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what happens in the `// stuff here` section.

Essentially, it comes down using a pre-GCD form of concurrency.  If you're targeting 10.5, then you also have `NSOperation` at your disposal.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to support Leopard, you could always go back to old school ["`NSThread`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (<-- documentation linked here), which continues to be fully supported up and through 10.9 & beyond.

[Blocks and dispatch_queue_t came in with MacOS 10.6 & iOS 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29).